# About a homemade SLA battery charger

Tags: resistors, battery-charging, circuit-analysis

After assembling [a simple emergency light kit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64800/constructing-a-simple-emergency-light-kit), it's time to build the battery charger.

**Details**: Most of the time, the battery won't be used and the circuit will be always connected to the energy source. It's necessary to avoid overcharge.

The circuit has educational purpose, so being simple is a must. I'm also trying to build it only with components that I already have (a bunch of resistors, capacitors, transistors and none IC).

**Circuit**

[image]
This schematics is [completely based on this text](http://homemadecircuitsandschematics.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/led-emergency-light-circuit-with.html).

By the author of the text, R1 is set as:

> P2 [here, R1] is set such that at 14.6V (across the battery terminals) the base LED becomes very dim, hardly visible, and at 12.5V it's brightly lit.

**Doubts**

- Do you think that this is a good approach to this problems (considering the limitations)?
- Wouldn't it be better if I just kept the voltage in 7v?
- What is the best way to test this circuit? I'm not sure that I understand the potentiometer role.

As always, any kind of suggestion or critic will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your 6.3V battery is the same as the author's battery?

Comment: You say the schematic is "completely based on this text" yet I see no similarities when it comes to charging the battery.

Comment: @jippie he's using a 12v sla battery, but I think that the only difference will be on how the potentiometer is adjusted.

Comment: 7V sounds more plausible than 14, that is correct.

Comment: @Andyaka This circuit is based on the second solution created by him. First he uses 2 npn transistors and then, 1 pnp, as you can see here.

Comment: This circuit could damage the battery - what is the dc voltage coming from the bridge rectifier? And what is the maximum voltage you can continuously charge the battery with? Will this take into account variations in AC supplies coming into your house? I don't see anything that looks like a voltage regulation circuit so I have worries.

Comment: @Andyaka, with the capacitor, I'm seeing 11.8v after the bridge retifier (my transformer is a 220v-9v). I've read that 2.3v per cell is secure to continuously charge the battery, so 7v seems to me enough.

You're right, I'm not taking it into account and there isn't any voltage regulator in use. What you think about using a fuse to protect the system?